# Dynamically add routes at compile time in Scotty

Tags: haskell, template-haskell, scotty

Is it possible to add routes dynamically at compile time through a config file by using Template Haskell or any other way.

Scotty has a function [addRoute](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty-0.9.1/docs/Web-Scotty.html#v:addroute) but I want to use it dynamically.

Example

```
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as LTB

sampleRoutes :: [(String, LTB.Text)]
sampleRoutes = [("hello", LTB.pack "hello"), ("world", LTB.pack "world")]
```

I want to iterate over the sampleRoutes array and define routes and responses at compile time.

```
import Web.Scotty

main = scotty 3000 $ do
  middleware logStdoutDev
  someFunc sampleRoutes
```

Comment: Without using TH I have been able to do `do {middleware logStdoutDev; ((get ("/hello")) (text (LTB.pack ("hello")))) ; ((get ("/world")) (text (LTB.pack ("world"))))}` How can I compose actions dynamically inside the `ScottyM ()`monad based on some list?

Comment: small *hint*: you can remove (most if not all) of your `LTB.pack` in there if you just use `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}` (and `Text` instead `String` might be a good idea too if you don't really need the `String = [Char]` part)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so given the above list, I am assuming you are looking to something that is equivalent to writing the following by hand:

```
{-! LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Web.Scotty
import Data.String

main = scotty 3000 $ do
  middleware logStdoutDev
  get (fromString $ '/' : "hello") (text "hello")
  get (fromString $ '/' : "world") (text "world")
```

The good news is, there's nothing in there that would need any TH magic!

Remember, `addroute` / `get` are just regular functions that return a `ScottyM ()` value. If I have

```
r1 = get (fromString $ '/' : "hello") (text "hello")
r2 = get (fromString $ '/' : "world") (text "world")
```

then the preceding `main` function is exactly equivalent to

```
main = do
  middleware logStdoutDev
  r1
  r2
```

This, and the common structure of `r1` and `r2` suggests the following solution:

```
import Control.Monad (forM_)

main = do
  middleware logStdoutDev
  forM_ sampleRoutes $ \(name, response) -> 
    get (fromString $ '/':name) (text response)
```

Comment: I didn't about `forM_`. Thanks a lot. Too bad I couldn't use TH. I was looking for an opportunity to learn it.